# TypeConverter.ConvertFromString doesn't throw FormatException when trying to convert invalid enum value

Tags: c#, typeconverter

While trying to track down a bug in an internal conversion library, I stumbled upon unexpected behavior with `TypeConverter.ConvertFromString` when trying to convert to an enum type.

The following method an enum type can be used to demonstrate the issue:

```cs
MyEnum? Convert(string s)
{
    var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(MyEnum)); // Creates an EnumConverter
    try
    {
        var converted = converter.ConvertFromString(s);
        return converted != null ? (MyEnum)converted : null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"({e.GetType().Name}: Failed to convert {s} to {nameof(MyEnum)} - {e.Message})");
        return null;
    }
}

enum MyEnum { First , Second }
```

Calling this method with valid enum values (even for int values that are outside the definition of `MyEnum`) yields the expected result:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Convert("0")); // First
Console.WriteLine(Convert("Second")); // Second
Console.WriteLine(Convert("2")); // 2
```

Calling the method with invalid enum values also yields the expected result:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Convert("x")); // (FormatException: Failed to convert x to MyEnum - x is not a valid value for MyEnum.)
Console.WriteLine(Convert("1.2")); // (FormatException: Failed to convert 1.2 to MyEnum - 1.2 is not a valid value for MyEnum.)
```

However, for certain values that i would *expect* to also be invalid - a string with int values separated by `,` - the conversion succeeds in a way I cannot explain - neither *why* it succeeds nor *the conversion* it does:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Convert("1,2")); // 3
Console.WriteLine(Convert("2,3")); // 3
Console.WriteLine(Convert("3,4")); // 7
Console.WriteLine(Convert("4,5")); // 5
```

Handling this would be easy enough - one could for instance test if the input contains `,`, and if so return `null` straight away - so that is not the issue of this question.

**Question:** I would however very much like to know *why* these conversions with `"1,2"` etc. doesn't throw an exception. And I am also very curious to know what the logic behind the result in these cases is.

The above code is tested with both .NET 6 and .NET 7, but I can also confirm the same behavior with .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: I initially thought it might have something to do with the current culture, since my local culture has `,` as the decimal separator, but I have tried running with different kinds of cultures having different decimal separators, and the result appears to be consistent in all cases.

Comment: The comma-separated value notation is a way to format `Flags` enums, so the resulting value is the bitwise `or` of the specified values. That the converter performs this logic whether or not the type is annotated with `Flags`, and whether or not the numbers represent tags, could be considered a bug, but then, there's plenty of weirdness (legacy or otherwise) in the generic converter classes. Note that `Enum.Parse` does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Feel free to post that as an answer @JeroenMostert so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma-separated value notation is a way to format `Flags` enums, so the resulting value is the bitwise `or` of the specified values.

That the converter performs this logic whether or not the type is annotated with `Flags`, and whether or not the numbers represent tags, could be considered a bug, but then, there's plenty of weirdness (legacy or otherwise) in the generic converter classes.

Note that `Enum.Parse` does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: NB: This answer is a copy of the comment from @JeroenMostert, so I can accept it and "close" the question. If Jeroen would like to post the answer himself, I will be sure to accept it and delete this one.